# What is the maximum character "account" level?

Tags: ios, minigore2

You can see the level in the menu. This level is from killing zombies. It unlocks in-game content.

I'm asking about the "account" level (33 in the screenshot), not character level.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the maximum character level is 99

Comment: Source maybe :) ?

Comment: His name is _John Gore_, he must know what he's talking about. Seriously though I can't find anything online saying what the max level is. Not even the official site. Even if it is level 99 that would take forever to reach without playing constantly for days on end.

Comment: Oh, I don't saw his nick earlier!